# React useRouteMatch not showing nested link content

Tags: reactjs, react-hooks

I have a demo [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-p5vdeq?file=Info.tsx)

I have two pages Home and Info

Info has a nested nav that when clicked should display the component
below the nav but still show the Info heading and info links.

Currentlt it shows the correct url but shows a blank screen.

What am I doing wrong here

```
import React from "react";
import { Link, Route, useRouteMatch, Switch } from "react-router-dom";

import InfoOne from "./InfoOne";
import InfoTwo from "./InfoTwo";

const Info: React.FC = () => {
  const { path, url } = useRouteMatch();
  return (
    <div>
      <h2>Info</h2>
      <ul>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/linkone`}>Info Link One</Link>
        </li>
        <li>
          <Link to={`${url}/linktwo`}>Info Link Two</Link>
        </li>
      </ul>

      <div>
        <Switch>
          <Route path={`${path}/linkone`}>
            <InfoOne />
          </Route>
          <Route path={`${path}/linktwo`}>
            <InfoTwo />
          </Route>
        </Switch>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default Info;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is in your `Main.tsx` .

You do not need `exact` here:

```
<Route path="/info" component={Info} />
```

By adding `exact` It does mounted its own component on every route. You just need to remove it. Here is working code: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-r7kqzj?file=Main.tsx